# How to prevent double click to zoom on chrome android when desktop site is on?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, events

How can I prevent zooming of the browser on double click in Google Chrome when the desktop site is enabled. I tried adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` , but it didn't work. And I also tried adding the `event.preventDefault()` method on `window.ondblclick` event, but this too didn't work.

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
let time_stamp = 0; // Or Date.now()
window.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event_) {
    if (event_.timeStamp - time_stamp < 300) { // A tap that occurs less than 300 ms from the last tap will trigger a double tap. This delay may be different between browsers.
        event_.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    time_stamp = event_.timeStamp;
});
```